# crystal reports xi show only group headings

Tags: sql, crystal-reports-xi

I have a crystal report that has data grouped by employee like this:

```
Employee 1:
  -Name
  -Orders written
  -Etc
```

The report displays all this information. but what I want to do is make a list that is only the employee and when clicked on will drill down to the info. Even better would be is there a way to make a drop down to select employee?

The report is created from a sql query command with parameters for date to get the amount of orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports has DrillDown functionality. Maybe this will help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227343(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I only have the crystal report xi program itself not visual studio.